# Unknown custom element: <v-row> - did you register the component correctly error

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i have two components parent and child inside it like that:

```
<parent-comp>
    <links-encoded v-if="isEncodeOpen"></links-encoded>
</parent-comp>
```

the vue file has code like that

```
import LinksEncodedComponent from './links-encoded/links-encoded.component.vue';


    components: {
        'links-encoded': LinksEncodedComponent
    },
```

links encoded html

```
<v-flex class="text-sm-left">
            <v-form>
                <v-container>
                  <v-row>
                <v-col cols="12" sm="12">
                    <v-text-field
                      value="test" name="John"
                      label="Protocol"
                      readonly
                    ></v-text-field>
                  </v-col>
                </v-row>
                </v-container>
              </v-form>
            </v-flex>
```

this for example works with no errors

```
<v-flex class="text-sm-left">
            <v-form>
                <v-container>
              <v-col cols="12" sm="12">
                <v-textarea
                name="input-7-1"
                label="Default style"
                value="The Woodman"
              ></v-textarea>
              </v-col>
            </v-container>
          </v-form>
        </v-flex>
```

how is that possiable?? maybe its becuuse I am using version 1.5?

Comment: Please give a better example, none of the examples you show has any reference to the v-row you're getting an error about.

Comment: you forget to close the `v-row` in link encoded HTML.

Comment: its not that. i didnt copy paste the code well. fixed

Comment: did u import vuetify correctly ? plz show imports as well as the code where u register vuetify

Comment: yes, all my other components working properly

Comment: the interesting part: if i change v-col to v-textarea i dont get any erros

Answer (score 5):

VRow and VCol are components only introduced in Vuetify 2.x. Vuetify 1.5 uses VLayout and VFlex for grid layouts.